# ¿Cómo almacenar resultado obtenido de una tarea ejecutada por un Timer en un EJB para consultar al dia siguiente?

Tags: ejb, timer

Estoy ejecutando un servicio de cumpleaños, para evitar que se ejecute el servicio cada vez que se haga la petición al servidor, he implementado un Timer, con su respectiva TimerTask que es la que accede directamente a la llamada del servicio.

```
    @Stateless
public class CumplesTimer {
    private Date horaEjecucion;
    private Calendar c;
    private int tiempoRepeticion = 86400000;// tiempo de repeticion 24h
    private String mes;

    //LISTAS DE CUMPLEANNOS
    private List<Cumple> cumplesDelMes;

    //TIMER Y TIMERTASK
    private Timer cumplesTimer;
    private CumplesUnaVezXDiaTask task;

    public CumplesTimer() {
        // Inicializo las variables...

    }

    @Schedule
    public void TimerExecute() {
        // Obtengo el mes actual
        mes = Integer.toString(Calendar.MONTH); 
        task.setMes(mes);// Setear el mes a la tarea
        boolean faltanDatos = false;

        if (outOfTime()) { //si la hora es posterior a la indicada
            if(cumplesDelMes.isEmpty()){
                faltanDatos = true;
            }else{
                c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 1); 
                faltanDatos = false;
            }
        } else {
            faltanDatos = true;
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        }
        try {
            if(faltanDatos){
                //Si la lista de cumples esta vacia ejecuto el timer con la hora actual                 
                cumplesTimer.schedule(task, horaEjecucion, tiempoRepeticion);

                guardarDatos();//con este metodo guardo los datos recuperados en task
                }else{ //Si no estan
                horaEjecucion = c.getTime();
                cumplesTimer.schedule(task, horaEjecucion);
                guardarDatos();
                }               
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void guardarDatos() {
        cumplesDelMes = task.getCumplesDelMes();
    }
```

La idea es que en este EJB almacene los cumpleaños que obtuvo de ejecutar el servicio, de forma que si ejecuta fuera de hora (por cualquier motivo), y hay datos que mostrar, no vuelva a pegarle al servicio, sino que use esos datos que ya existen, y se mantenga programado para ejecutarse al día siguiente. Por el contrario si no hay datos que se ejecute en el momento para obtener el resultado y se mantenga programado para ejecutarse con la periodicidad indicada.

```
public class CumplesUnaVezXDiaTask extends TimerTask {

    private CumpleMesHelper helper; //helper que crea y ejecuta el servicio 
    private String mes;

    // LISTAS DE CUMPLEANNOS
    private List<Cumple> cumplesDelMes;

    public CumplesUnaVezXDiaTask() {
        // Inicializo las variables...
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Ejecutar el servicio de cumpleannos del mes
        cumplesDelMes = helper.mostrarCumplesMes(mes);
    }
```

}

Esta es la tarea que se llama cuando el Timer lo decide. Simplemente ejecuta el helper, delegándole a este la responsabilidad de crear y ejecutar el servicio con la configuración necesaria.

Y por último muestro el Servlet que ejecuta al timer, desde aquí anteriormente se ejecutaba directamente en el `doGet` al helper cada vez que se hacia una peticion. Por esto la idea del timer en el medio de ambos para evitar sobrecargar al servidor con ejecuciones que ya tienen los datos conseguidos.

```
public class CumpleMesServlet extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 9074272368098705887L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 

    doGet(request, response); 

}


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
//      String mes = request.getParameter("mes"); --esta ejecucion esta sustituida dentro del timer --
//      CumpleMesHelper cumpleMesHelper = new CumpleMesHelper(); --esta ejecucion se sustituyo por la llamada al timer --
//      List<Cumple> cumples = cumpleMesHelper.mostrarCumplesMes(mes); --esta ejecucion se sustituyo por la llamada al timer --     

        CumplesTimer timer = new CumplesTimer();
        timer.TimerExecute();
        List<Cumple> cumples = timer.getCumplesDelMes();


        try {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");
            JsonArray jsonArray = getJson(cumples);
            out.print(jsonArray);
            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

En principio, y a mi modo de ver, deberia funcionar, pero la realidad es que no se esta almacenando los datos. ¿Como deberia solucionar esto? Se me ocurre alguna entidad a la que pueda otorgarle la responsabilidad de guardarlo la lista de los cumpleaños obtenidos, para que no este ni en el Timer, ni en la Task, pero no estoy seguro.

Si alguien intento algo parecido antes, o ve que estoy cometiendo algun error, por favor agradecere toda la ayuda posible. Muchas gracias.